# No command history recall in PyDev debug console

Tags: debugging, python-3.x, pydev

I'm having problems getting my project to stop at a breakpoint in a console that supports command recall (via up arrow) and command editing.  Obviously I'm new to Eclipse and to PyDev.  Config advise appreciated!!

It's a simple Python project which runs locally.  When I hit a breakpoint, the console that comes up does not support command recall (via up arrow) or command editing.  When I hit up arrow, the cursor marches line by line upwards.  When I up arrow to a line containing a previous command and hit an editing key, e.g, DEL, the cursor immediately jumps to the bottom of the window (and does not bring the rest of the command with it).  This console also does not display a python command prompt '>>>'

```
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 29008)
mainIndex        ## I type
251
n                ## I type
1
```

When I load the same project and run an interactive PyDev console, I do get the Python prompt and the desired command recall and editing, but when I execute the module (e.g, to hit a breakpoint), the runfile(...) command does not return control.  I have enabled the option 'connect console to a Debug Session' in Preferences/PyDev/Interactive Console.

```
PyDev Interactive Console
>>> import sys; import os; os.chdir("/home/bobhy/Dropbox/MOOC/HRA/emailMatch"); print('{} {}, cwd={}'.format((sys.executable or sys.platform), sys.version, os.getcwd()))
/usr/bin/python3 3.3.2+ (default, Feb 28 2014, 00:52:16) 
[GCC 4.8.1], cwd=/home/bobhy/Dropbox/MOOC/HRA/emailMatch
PyDev console: using default backend (IPython not available).
>>> print ("{}...".format(n))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.3/code.py", line 90, in runcode
  exec(code, self.locals)
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined
>>> runfile('fuzzyMatch.py')
0...
                    ## wishing for prompt here, but runfile doesn't return control
```

Annnd finally, if I run the project and let it hit a breakpoint, as in first scenario,  right click on the project scope in Debug window, and select PyDev/Debug Console from the context menu, I get what is apparently a 3rd flavor of console:

```
PyDev Debug Console [1]
>>> import sys; import os; os.chdir("${container_loc}"); print('{} {}, cwd={}'.format((sys.executable or sys.platform), sys.version, os.getcwd()))
[Current context]: File "/home/bobhy/Dropbox/MOOC/HRA/emailMatch/fuzzyMatch.py", line 53, in main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bobhy/devtools/eclipse-kepler-SR2-linux-X86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.4.1.201403181715/pysrc/pydevd_console.py", line 138, in runcode
Exec(code, self.frame.f_globals, self.frame.f_locals)
  File "/home/bobhy/devtools/eclipse-kepler-SR2-linux-X86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.4.1.201403181715/pysrc/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError
: 
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '${container_loc}'
>>> a = 'abc'              ## this variable does show up in the Variables window
```

But this one keeps hiding behind the debug console and I can't use it.

Using Python 3.3, Pydev 3.4.1, Eclipse-Kepler Service Release 2, Linux Mint Petra 16